# My Editor can't detect method "OnTriggerEnter"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to c# scripting and I'm trying to write a script for pickups to get destroyed on collision. Tried calling the method "OnTriggerEnter" but my editor doesn't seem to recognize it. Help?

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
   if(!other.CompareTag("Player")) return;

   Destroy(gameObject);

}
```

Comment: Do you want it so that when the player collides with the pickup, the pickup will be destroyed? Also, what gameObject is this script attached to?

Comment: Is it a 2d or a 3d game?

Comment: Try adding a Debug.Log befor you return to see if the method is called